# gpg: decryption failed: No secret key

Tags: gnupg, macos

I cannot seem to get gnupg to decrypt files encrypted with my keys. I've tried migrating my secret key from an old laptop to a new one, and I keep getting the same error:

```
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

I tried exporting my public, secret, and subkeys from my old laptop as follows:

```
gpg --export MYKEYID > pub.key
gpg --export-secret-keys MYKEYID > sec.key
gpg --export-secret-subkeys MYKEYID > sub.key
```

I then copied them to my new laptop, and imported them as follows:

```
gpg --import pub.key
gpg --import sec.key
gpg --import sub.key
```

Then I edited the key to give it ultimate trust:

```
gpg --edit-key MYKEYID

gpg> trust
...
Your decision? 5
Do you really want to set this key to ultimate trust? (y/N) y
```

yet no matter what, it fails to decrypt:

```
gpg --decrypt -v encryptedfile.gpg
gpg: public key is E78E22A13ED8B15D
gpg: encrypted with ELG key, ID E78E22A13ED8B15D
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

Version on old laptop:

```
gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.21
libgcrypt 1.7.6
```

Version on new laptop:

```
gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG/MacGPG2) 2.2.3
libgcrypt 1.8.1
```

Comment: Does `gpg --list-keys` show your private key?

Comment: Does `--list-secret-keys` show your secret key? Maybe you need to set (even though the manpage says otherwise) `allow-secret-key-import`. Also: Voting to migrate to SU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was entirely my fault. I'm not sure what happened, but the file I was trying to decrypt was not encrypted by my key. I tried a different file and it worked.

I'm not sure how that happened, but testing the same file on the old machine first would have saved me a ton of time :).

Answer (score 7):

This message can also happen if your key is protected with a passphrase, and your pinentry program isn't working properly.

In this case, gpg can't get the passphrase to unlock the decryption key. If this is the case, `gpg --list-keys` will show the correct key, but `gpg -d -v` will appear to select the correct key and then just hang for a while before giving up. This is it waiting for the pinentry that never actually returns.

The steps depend on your specific environment, but checking (or creating) the `pinentry-program` option in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` is a good place to start. In my case (on OS X with Homebrew-installed `gpg` and `pinentry-mac`) I had to create that file with the following contents:

```
pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry-mac
```

You may need to adjust as needed for whatever your preferred pinentry program is.

Comment: Thank you. no passphrase entry was the problem in my case. Ive preset the passphrase like so, `gpg-preset-passphrase --preset --passphrase <my-passphrase> <key-id>`. But i still get the error. could you please help?

Answer (score 3):

I randomly started getting the error

```
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

as well, when attempting to decrypt files.  Strangely, GPG was telling me that the files were encrypted with a different key ID than my own (despite identifying my name and the date of the key’s creation correctly).  I restarted my computer and the problem went away.

I’m guessing there is a bug where some bit can get misaligned in the GPG daemon’s memory, and then it will need restarting.

Answer (score 2):

I got the error:

```
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

after I closed a gpg prompt with Ctrl+C, so maybe there was still some state hanging around.

I fixed it by killing the gpg-agent process:

```
$ ps aux | grep gpg-agent
user             76882   0.0  0.0  4297004    996   ??  Ss   11:51AM   0:00.02 gpg-agent --homedir /Users/user/.gnupg --use-standard-socket --daemon

$ kill 76882
```

Answer (score 1):

Also for me, as for [Jackson](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/203098/177465) the solution was to reboot, but I want to give the context in which I hit the problem, in case it can be useful to whoever comes to this thread.

I hitted the `gpg: decryption failed: No secret key` error one day when trying to retrieve a password from my store using `pass`, which I use daily, and the issue was solved by rebooting. Before that error, the closest to "keys" things that I had done were:

- the day before, generating an SSH key with `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048`, which to me seems unrelated;
- the day itself, temporarly commenting out the line `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` from my `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

I landed on this answer but my resolution was different:
In my case the problem was different user accounts on a Windows machine:
My personal user was getting a different result of `gpg --list-keys` than when I logged in via the Service User on the same machine.
So when the Service User triggered my decryption via script, it was not finding the correct key and therefore throwing `gpg: decryption failed: No secret key`.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error `gpg: decryption failed: No secret key` when trying to decrypt a message that I encrypted for someone else.

To be able to decrypt it, I had to encrypt the message using `--recipient` parameter 2 times with both the receiver and sender ID (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597188/encryption-decryption-with-multiple-keys).

Answer (score -1):

try to use root privileges, such as sudo gpg ... I think that gpg elevated without permissions does not refer to file permissions, but system